# Wildcard in named ranged

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code within my VBA:

```
Call add_validList (Sheet1.Range("MyCell_1_Type"), "=datalist"
```

How can I introduce a wildcard for the named range MyCell_1_Type?

I have a number of these named range i.e MyCell_1_Type, MyCell_2_Type, MyCell_3_Type, MyCell_4_Type,............., MyCell_1000_Type.

This is the solution I am after:

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
Call add_validList (Sheet1.Range("MyCell_&"*"&_Type"), "=datalist"
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function

```
Public Function GetNamedRanges(ByVal part1 As String, ByVal part2 As String) As Range
    Dim itm As Name, r As Range, found As Long

    For Each itm In Names
        found = InStr(itm.Name, part1)
        If found > 0 And InStr(found + 1, itm.Name, part2) > 0 Then
            If r Is Nothing Then Set r = Range(itm) Else Set r = Union(r, Range(itm))
        End If
    Next
    Set GetNamedRanges = r
End Function
```

To call it use `GetNamedRanges("MyCell_", "_Type")`

Comment: Hi Paul, this seem to work but what I failed to mention earlier is that the data set looks like this:                                                         
MyCell_AA_Type,                                                                MyCell_BB_Type,                                                         
MyCell_BOB_Type,                                                                MyCell_ZEN_Type. The middle text variable,

Comment: That's fine: it will find any defined name that contains the text "MyCell_" and also contains the text "_Type" (in this order) with any text in between them, and it returns the union of all named ranges found

Comment: Thanks, Paul. It worked perfectly. I am very grateful. Regards

Answer (score 0):

How about for loop?

You can use for loop to operate 1 to 1000 times, For example,

```
For i = 1 To 1000
    Call add_validList(Sheet1.Range("MyCell_" & i & "_Type"), "=datalist")
Next i
```

Change to below, Beware that this will refer to named range in a whole workbook.

```
Dim n
For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    Call add_validList(Sheet1.Range(n.Name), "=datalist")
Next i
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this may not work in my function. Is there a user defined function that can be used?

Comment: Sorry, I've revise the answer. please check again.